# How to execute a page in specific time interval without delaying other pages execution in Jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to execute a page like login page in a specific time interval but, it should not delay other pages execution in Jmeter.

Comment: What do you mean "in a specific time interval"? if loading page more than x seconds stop and return error?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter waits for response from the previous sampler before starting the next one so the only way of achieving your setup is putting the "login page" under a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Alternative option could be placing all the "pages" under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/), this way the requests you put under the Parallel Controller will be fired at the same time and none of them will wait for another, but in case of multiple iterations JMeter will wait for all "pages" to complete prior to starting the next iteration